# SQLite Convert to SQLite Datetime Format from ANY datetime format

Tags: date, sqlite

Coming out of an Oracle background converting dates from any format to any format is really easy.

How is this done in SQLite?  I've searched and searched for answers and most of the answers simply say... Save your date/strings in SQLite in one single format which is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`.  This seems rigid to me.

I don't have that luxury as my data is stored in this format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS am` ex. 3/7/2020 8:02:31 AM.

**NOTE:** For single days/months my date values do not contain leading zeros and my time is NOT in military time.

How do I tell SQLite what my date format is so that I can correctly convert my stored dates to SQLite datetime formats?

> Convert from SQLite Date Format to Oracle Date Example:

In Oracle I would simply use the to_date function like so

`to_date('2019-03-07 15:39:34', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

All one needs to do is to tell the function what the date format is... and then it spits out a date.... easy peasy.  What this example does is convert a SQLite date formated string to a date that Oracle recognizes as a date.  It doesn't matter what the format is in as I tell the function what format to expect.

> How do I Convert Dates in SQLite from any format to the SQLite Format?

Converting from SQLite's date format string to ANY date is easy as there are functions built in that do this easily... but how to do this the other way round?

Comment: You can see the formats that sqlite date and time functions understand [in their documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Things that don't match one of those formats make them return null. If your dates aren't stored in one of those formats, you have to fix them or do something that doesn't involve sqlite's functions.

Comment: Yeah... I've read thru that documentation several times over hoping to find a way I can work with SQLite dates in the same manner I've been working with them for over 10 years out of Oracle.  Sadly... SQLite is lacking here I guess.  So much work to get these dates into the 'special' SQLite string format.  Ugh...